# How should I implement a Game Over menu in Android?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es2

By *Game Over menu*, I mean a menu displayed when you die, with an option to play again.

I have two approaches in mind:

1. **Use OpenGL**

   Have some button textures ready. When the character dies, draw them. Listen for events on those textures.
2. **Use a view**

   (This is what I'm doing now.) When the user opens the game, I have a basic activity, along with a basic view with a `FrameLayout`: The root is a `GlSurfaceView` and there's a menu on top of it (embedded in a `LinearLayout`). When the user hits "Play", this menu is translated away (using a translate animation) from the screen, leaving only the `GlSurfaceView` visible, with which the user can interact. I was thinking of implementing something similar when the game ends, but I'm not sure where to start.

I don't particularly like the first approach, since implementing button events in OpenGL seems hard.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question since there are so many approaches so the only thing I can do is tell you what I choose to do in my own games.

I run game states, for example when I'm playing `gameState = GAMEPLAY` , then when my character dies I change my game state to `gameState=gameOverScreen`, and using if-statements in my rendering and update methods I check for all the game states, and `if (gameState==gameOverScreen)` I stop rendering and updating gameplay and bring up my game over menu and change my onTouch method (in `update()`) to fit the new screen.

This is just one way and Im not sure if its the best way, but there you go.